# Extracting Option<String> fields with yaml_rust

Tags: rust, yaml, ownership

New rust user here.
I'm trying to use `yaml_rust` to parse my config files, and spotted a difficulty.
I am trying to keep `Option<...>` values to handle the possibility that a field is missing or null. Well, in yaml_rust you have these as_xxx accessors which look so handy, returning exactly that. Almost. There's `as_str` returning `Option<&str>`, but no `as_string` returning `Option<String>`.
So I concocted the following (preliminary lines as from `yaml_rust` usage example):

```
    let yml_str = fs::read_to_string(file_name).unwrap();
    let mut docs = YamlLoader::load_from_str(&yml_str).unwrap();
    let doc = &docs[0];

    let artifact_id = 
        if let Some(str) = doc["artifact_id"].as_str() {
            Some(str.to_string())
        } else {
            None
        };
```

Needless to say, it seems to me... verbose? Is it possibly the way to go?

Just to show what I tried: the `into_xxx` accessors do list a ``into_string() `method)`Option`, but I spotted a (for me) obscure error. What is obscure is that the error seems related to` doc["artifact_id"]`, but if I append` doc["artifact_id"].as_str()`the error vanishes, while when I append`doc["artifact_id"].into string()``` it appears.

The following example shows the error.

```
use yaml_rust::YamlLoader;
fn main() {
    let yml_str = "[]";
    let docs = YamlLoader::load_from_str(&yml_str).unwrap();
    let doc = &docs[0];
    let _test = doc["artifact_id"].into_string();
}
```

The following one doesn't.

```
use yaml_rust::YamlLoader;
fn main() {
    let yml_str = "[]";
    let docs = YamlLoader::load_from_str(&yml_str).unwrap();
    let doc = &docs[0];
    let _test = doc["artifact_id"].as_str();
}
```

Comment: `doc["artifact_id"].as_str().map (String::from)` [should do what you want](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a2a6ce357d757ab51dc15aa521335da6), although I would advise you to use `serde_yaml` to directly parse into a `struct` with the expected format.

Comment: Many thanks! Actually if there's the support for expected ```structs```s I will investigate serde_yaml.